# General techniques for proving a function is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions

I am curious on different ways to prove that a real-valued function $f$ is Borel measurable. If we denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by $\mathcal{B}$, I'm aware that TFAE:

- $f^{-1}(-\infty, c)\in \mathcal{B}$ $ \forall c\in \mathbb{R}$
- $f^{-1}(c, \infty) \in \mathcal{B}$ $ \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$
- $f^{-1}(a,b) \in \mathcal{B}$ $ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
- $f$ is Borel measurable.

Are there any other ways, or does one just play games with the first three to get the fourth?

Comment: You could equally well use closed intervals instead of open. What definition are you using for "$f$ is Borel measurable"? Is it $f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal B$ for all open sets $U$?

Comment: Actually, most of the time you use the fact that Borel functions are closed under composition

Comment: My edit was for some obvious typos only.